# How do I "ASCII armor" my MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, .net, string, encoding, ascii

How do I [ASCII armor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_Armor) a memory stream? ASCII armoring is the process of encoding a binary data to a printable ASCII string. This is used for example in encryption.

Is there any standard way to do this, also with decoding support, in C#? Like an API? Otherwise, how can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should almost always use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (or hex) to represent arbitrary binary data in printable text:

```
byte[] binary = ...;
string text = Convert.ToBase64String(binary);

...

string text = ...;
byte[] binary = Convert.FromBaseString(text);
```

You can use [`MemoryStream.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) to convert all the data in a `MemoryStream` into a byte array. Doing this in a streaming fashion would take slightly more work, but would be feasible - and there's support for it in the framework using the [`ToBase64Transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tobase64transform.aspx) and [`FromBase64Transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.frombase64transform.aspx) classes, which you can use to chain a stream with a [`CryptoStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx). The result will be an ASCII-encoded base64 stream.

Comment: Shouldn't a MemoryStream already be backed by a byte-array? Wouldn't ToArray() just make a copy?

Comment: @Bengie: Yes, it just makes a copy. But it's a conversion as far as the caller is concerned. (There's also `GetBuffer` which *doesn't* make a copy, but which returns the underlying buffer.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use base64 encoding to get a reasonably compact ASCII representation of binary data:

```
string data = Convert.ToBase64String(theMemoryStream.ToArray());
```

Use the `Convert.FromBase64String` method to decode the string.

Answer (score 2):

Check this what have i done for my password, using [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) and [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Methods

> Check the documentation example that may clear the picture more to
>   you.. you can pass you byte array as parameter and then check what
>   will you get.. The link specified on `ASCII armor` there are list of most used forms of binary-to-text encodings, in which `base64` available. you can work on this using .net libraries.

*//encode*

```
public static string EncodeString(string s)
        {
            byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(b, 0, b.Length);
        }
```

*//decode*

```
public static string DecodeString(string s)
{
    byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
    return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b);
}
```

Comment: I don't think I'd call "encoding with the platform default encoding" **encryption**. (I'd also recommend against using the platform default encoding in almost all cases.)